# Error message in Exit-Relay Tor

Tags: exit-relays

I'm running an Exit-Relay Tor through SSH and it shows an error message:

```
Tried to establish rendezvous on non-OR circuit with purpose Acting as 
rendezvous (pending)'
```

and it duplicates itself many times(15 and more) 
this is my torrc file:

```
Nickname human
ORPort 443
ExitRelay 0
SocksPort 0
ControlSocket 0
DisableDebuggerAttachment 0
ContactInfo human@gmail.com
```

I can't find an answer to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm running a Exit-Relay

No you aren't. Your torrc clearly says `ExitRelay 0` which means you are **NOT** an exit.

> Tried to establish rendezvous on non-OR circuit with purpose Acting as 
>   rendevous (pending)

This isn't a problem for you to solve. https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/15618